# AutoML Vision: Error: ImportData stopped due to too many errors

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I selected to create a dataset in the AutoML Vision UI like so:

[image]

[image]

I get this: Error: ImportData stopped due to too many errors.

[image]

Notice that it tells me that I have errors in my csv file, but it does not tell me what errors are, so how can I debug?

I tried this:

```
>cat operation-get-status.sh 
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  printf "usage: get-training-status.sh [operation-id]\n"
  exit 1
fi

export OPERATION_ID="$1"

#export OPERATION_ID="ICN21697762462531584"
source set-vars.sh

curl -X GET \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/$REGION_NAME/operations/operation-id
```

But the response is not very helpful:

```
>./operation-get-status.sh IOD2963854538949263360
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "List of found errors:\t1.Field: name; Message: Required field is invalid\t",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "name",
            "description": "Required field is invalid"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which required field is invalid?

Comment: Getting the same error  while running google auto ml sample code. Did you figure out the issue? Link : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/automl/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/automl/

Comment: No. I switched to using the GUI instead.

Answer (score 0):

I go the same error on my GUI with uploaded CSVs. Tried to upload a single annotation from one video. Got the following error:

> Cannot move files across regions. Please use a regional bucket in the
> same location and with same storage class as AutoML. Required
> Location: us-central1, required location type: Region, required
> storage class: Standard.

After changing the type of bucket to the recommended settings, the upload was successful.

Comment: Plus, if start or time has too many numbers after the comma (e.g. 1.11111111), the import fails.